# How can I save the content of file as bytes in a variable?

Tags: python, file, byte

Given a text file, for example: `a.txt` , that his max-size is 16 bytes and it contains some text. How can I read all the content of this file (all the bytes of this file) and save it in variable without to open this file?
Namely, I don't want to do `open("a.txt", "r").read()` , but, I looking for something like:

```
a = bytes(`cat file.txt`)
```

In style of linux.
Can I do it in python ?

Comment: Without opening it? Even `cat` will need to read the file somehow. Why is `open('a.txt', 'rb').read()` unacceptable?

Comment: @C.Nivs because that I don't want to deal with closing of all the opening-files (and I going to open a lot of files)

Comment: @ukBaz It seen nice. how can I save the content of the file in a variable with these functions ?

Comment: You don't have to close them if you use the `with` context manager

Comment: @ukBaz I got this error: "name 'path' is not defined"

Comment: @ukBaz No. Ok. now it working. Now, according to my question, how can I read it up to 16 bytes? something like that: `.to_bytes(16, 'big')` - can I do something like that with `.read_bytes()`?

Comment: @ukBaz "16 bytes - this is the max_size of the file. and I want to read the file and if the file is smaller than 16 bytes so all the other bits will be 0 (pads). `big` and `little` are keyword while we use `to_bytes` function in python - no ?

Comment: So you mean endian-ness? Little endian and big endian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading bytes from a file and storing it in a variable can be done with `my_var = Path('a.txt').read_bytes()`

`bytes` has [rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.rjust) and [ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.ljust) to pad using the specified fill byte.

These can be combined to always give a result 16 bytes in length. e.g.

```
Path('a.txt').read_bytes().rjust(16, b'x')
```

Here is a fuller example of using this:

```py
from pathlib import Path


small_test = Path.home().joinpath('sml_test.txt')
big_test = Path.home().joinpath('big_test.txt')
small_payload = b'12345678'
full_payload = b'0123456789ABCDEF'


def write_test_files():
    small_test.write_bytes(small_payload)
    big_test.write_bytes(full_payload)


def read_test_files():
    data1 = small_test.read_bytes().rjust(16, b'x')
    data2 = big_test.read_bytes().rjust(16, b'x')
    print(f"{data1 = }")
    print(f"{data2 = }")


def main():
    write_test_files()
    read_test_files()
    small_test.unlink()
    big_test.unlink()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which gave the following output:

```
data1 = b'xxxxxxxx12345678'
data2 = b'0123456789ABCDEF'
```

Comment: and if I want to write it into a binary file with `struct.pack` - how can I do it? I trying to do it with `.to_bytes(16,'little')` for example - but I got this error: "'str' has no attribute 'to_bytes'"

Comment: in addition, what is the meaning of `b'x'` - x is the pad? if yes so why you don't using `b'0'` to pad it with zeros ?

Comment: My question is how can I print the variable `data1` from your code ?

Comment: see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213640/how-to-read-a-file-and-write-it-into-binary-file